# how to add checkout to rails appy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Could someone advise me how to add a checkout to my rails app.

i have the cart, users all that working, i just cant seem to find the code and im not good enought to built it yet for the checkout aspect.

any ideas any one?

Answer (score 0):

I am in the middle of reading Agile Web Development with Rails 4e (Rails 3.1).  In the book starting with chapter 6 you build a cart, send and receive emails and checkout.  They explain things every well and give you code on the website if you get stuck.  This might be something that can help you.

http://media.pragprog.com/titles/rails4/toc.pdf
http://pragprog.com/book/rails4/agile-web-development-with-rails